# Get app keywords with the iTunes Search API

Tags: ios, keyword, itunes

It looks like at this web site https://sensortower.com/ you can easily get the keywords an app publisher inserted when he submitted his app to Apple Store. I searched the docs (http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) of the Itunes Search API but I could not find any way to get the keywords. How did the do? Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, you cannot query for keywords.

What I think they do (and I am pretty certain) is that they query the app store regularly against a database they hold.

This database might hold keywords based on the descriptions and app titles of existing apps (basically just all words mentioned there). With this information they create random search term combinations and query the search API with it.

Afterwards they "guess" the app's keywords according to the position the app gets in the result list with the specified search terms. The higher its ranking the bigger might be the chance that it actually uses one of these keywords.